# Different quote strings for reply and forward in mu4e

Tags: mu4e

I have customized the `message-citation-line-format` variable and that format now appears in replies and forwards. But I would like to set different quote strings depending on whether I am replying or forwarding an email. For example, "On [date], [person] wrote:" when replying but a longer multi-line string (including "from," "to," and "date" fields) when forwarding. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

There's a hook run before message composition starts, so you can check the `last-command` to change the citation line conditionally:

```lisp
(defun citation-line-function ()
  (setq message-citation-line-format
        (if (eq last-command 'mu4e-compose-reply)
            "\nOn %a, %b %d %Y, %N wrote:\n"
          (let (addresses)
            (mapcar (lambda (to)
                      (let* ((name (or (car-safe to) ""))
                             (email (cdr-safe to)))
                        (push (format "%s <%s>" name email) addresses)))
                    (mu4e-message-field-at-point :to))
            (concat "\nFrom: %f\nTo: "
                    (mapconcat #'identity addresses ", ") "\n")))))

(add-hook 'mu4e-compose-pre-hook 'citation-line-function)
```

Note also that to insert a formatted citation line, you will need to update the `message-citation-line-function` variable as follows:

```lisp
(setq message-citation-line-function 'message-insert-formatted-citation-line)
```

Comment: Note that you also have to set `(setq message-citation-line-function 'message-insert-formatted-citation-line)` for this to take effect

Comment: Indeed, @Tyler. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @jagrg, for the pointer to ```mu4e-compose-pre-hook```. A modified version of this function is what I am using now. I will add it in an answer.

Comment: In the above answer, "%f" is for the "from" email address of the original email. Similar to that is there something for email addresses in the "To" and "Cc" field? I could not find any place where the different "variables" (like "%T" for "time" or "%a" for "Day") are listed.

Comment: When you forward a message the To field is blank, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I would like to include a line with the list of email addresses in the "To" and "Cc" fields of the _original message_ being forwarded (like it is done in gmail and `alpine` email client).

Comment: Ok, I added the To field of the original message. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of the function in the answer by @jagrg is what I am using now. Here it is.

```lisp
(defun citation-line-function ()
  (setq message-citation-line-format
    (if (eq mu4e-compose-type 'reply)
        "On %a %d %b %Y %T %z (%Z), %f wrote:\n"
      (if (eq mu4e-compose-type 'forward)
          "----- Forwarded message -----\nFrom: %f\nDate: %a %d %b %Y %T %z (%Z)\n\n"
        ))))

(add-hook 'mu4e-compose-pre-hook 'citation-line-function)
```

This gives something like the following `On Thu 21 Oct 2021 10:50:50 +0530 (IST), abc@def.com wrote:` when replying and when forwarding,

```
----- Forwarded message -----
From: abc@def.com
Date: Thu 21 Oct 2021 10:50:50 +0530 (IST)
```

Answer (score 0):

From `mu4e` 1.12.0 much of the mu4e-specific setup are removed and more of `message` is reused. This means the differing functions and settings for replying and forwarding from `message` applies, which by default gives a result similar to that asked in the original question.